# Activity Indicator won't stop spinning after WKWebView load finish

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am very new to Swift and iOS development so thank you so much in advance for helping me!

I have tried every example online and every page on this site and I cannot get my Activity Indicator to stop being displayed once the page completes loading in my WKWebview.

Any assistance would be so appreciated! Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController,     WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

@IBOutlet var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.uiDelegate = self

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    activityIndicator.isHidden = true
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Web/bulk_material_table", withExtension: "html")!
    webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    self.webView.load(request)


}

func showActivityIndicator(show: Bool) {
    if show {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    } else {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    showActivityIndicator(show: false)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    showActivityIndicator(show: true)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    showActivityIndicator(show: false)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
webView.uiDelegate = self
```

with

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

And it will work because

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    showActivityIndicator(show: false)
}
```

is `WKNavigationDelegate`'s delegate method.

Comment: WOW! So simple. Thank you. And thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Happy to help.. :)